# Lost information between scenes

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need to change scenes while the player press any key. it has worked perfectly, but when I `addForce` in `Y` axis and change scene, the loaded scene starts with `none` key pressed.

summing up: I walk and collide in `gameobject` and scene changes, the next scene start with the character walking, when I jump and collide in `gameobject` and change scenes, the next scene star white character stopped.

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't already using it, use [DontDestroyOnLoad](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html) on your player object, and of course don't add a new player in your new scene. That should work.

If it doesn't, I would probably try to either add new force in the new scene, maybe by somehow *storing* the force applied in the 1st scene in a GameHandler (that also should persist through scenes).

If that doesn't work maybe you have to consider not changing scenes, and simply moving the character to a new location in scene 1.

You haven't showed what you are doing or what you have tried so it's hard to answer really.

Comment: Sorry for the amount of information. I use DontDestroyOnLoad, and I have a simple character controller, I tryed input.getKey, input.getAxis but nothing worked. I can't add a new force in second scene, because if  the player stop pressing the key, the force should stop

Comment: I changed my las coment

Comment: I'm not sure what to do then... `Input.GetKey` should call when the key is held down, I honestly find it hard to believe it doesn't work. 
If you want a better answer you need to provide your code